# javascript dynamically remove text

Tags: javascript, button, removechild

I have successfully created a button which adds text to the webpage however I do not know a viable way to remove text once this has been created. The js code I have is:

```
    var addButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add button');

function addText () {
  var self = this;
  var weekParent = self.parentNode.parentNode;
  var textarea = self.parentNode.querySelector('textarea');
  var value = textarea.value;
  var item = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(value);

  item.appendChild(text)
  weekParent.appendChild(item);
}

function removeText() {
  //document.getElementbyId(-).removeChild(-);
}

for (i = 0; i < addButtons.length; i++) { 
    var self = addButtons[i];
    self.addEventListener("click", addText);
}
```

I have viewed various sources of help online including from this site however I simply cannot get any to work correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where you write the removeText function trigger on your html element

Comment: When you add the text; don't just append a <p> element with the text, append the text enclosed in a div with a custom class or unique ID and when you need to remove the text you can wipe the div's contents/remove the div which contains that text you've added; you can also append into a container and set the html of the container to blank it out to clear all text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it should be easy to locate the added `<p>` tag relative to the remove button that gets clicked.

```
function removeText() {
  var weekParent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var item = weekParent.querySelector("p");
  weekParent.removeChild(item);
}
```

If there is more than 1 `<p>` tag inside the weekParent you will need a more specific querySelector.